# InfoPath 2013 - Connect to ActiveDirectory using SOAP Web Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath

I would like to connect to Active Directory via InfoPath 2013 but I cannot find folder _vti_bin I working with SharePoint Foundation maybe this is a problem?

**I Found this:**

I recommend that you can follow the steps as below to implement it in your environment.

1. Go to the List tab of the list, and click “Customize Form” from the Ribbon.
2. From InfoPath, click the “DATA” tab and click “From SOAP Web Service” under “From Web Service”.
3. In Data Connection Wizard, type: http://< Site Name>/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx, then click “Next”.
4. Select “GetUserProfileByName” from the operation list and click “Next”, then click “Finish”.
5. In InfoPath Design, under “Fields”, select “Show advanced view”.
6. Click “DATA” tab, click “Form Load” from the Ribbon to display “Rules” window.
7. In “Rules” window, click “New”, select “Action”, add some specific “Details for” and “Condition”.
8. Publish the new form to the SharePoint list and test it in your environment.

**This can I see**

[image]